# Python Transpose Data with observation

Tags: python, pandas

I Have a question,

my initial df is like this :

```
Col 1   Col 2   Col 3

laura   purchase 1  dress23

laura   puchase 2   skirt55

laura   purchase 3  shirt47

laura   purchase 4  coat45

julia   puchase 1   skirt74

julia   purchase 2  short74

julia   purchase 3  coat14

julia   purchase 4  coat15
```

---

---

and I want to obtain it using the library Panda

```
Col 1   Purchase 1  Purchase 2  Purchase 3  Purchase 4
Laura   dresse23    skirt55     shirt47     coat45
Julia   skirt74    short74      coat14      coast10
```

Please, could you help me ?

It would be very nice,

thank you,

N

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, I do not see any pattern with your output and how you want it to be formatted.

Comment: I guess `coast10` should be `coat15`?

Answer (score 1):

Given data:

```
   col 1       col 2    col 3
0  laura  purchase 1  dress23
1  laura  purchase 2  skirt55
2  laura  purchase 3  shirt47
3  laura  purchase 4   coat45
4  julia  purchase 1  skirt74
5  julia  purchase 2  short74
6  julia  purchase 3   coat14
7  julia  purchase 4   coat15
```

The transformation:

```
df = df.pivot(index='col 1', columns='col 2', values='col 3').reset_index()
df = df.rename(columns={'col 1': 'name'})
df.columns.name = 'id'
print(df)
```

The result:

```
id   name purchase 1 purchase 2 purchase 3 purchase 4
0   julia    skirt74    short74     coat14     coat15
1   laura    dress23    skirt55    shirt47     coat45
```

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Method set_index, stack, reset_index

Use `set_index`, `unstack` and `reset_index`:

```
df.set_index(['Col 1','Col 2'])['Col 3'].unstack().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
Col 2  Col 1 puchase 1 puchase 2 purchase 1 purchase 2 purchase 3 purchase 4
0      julia   skirt74      None       None    short74     coat14     coat15
1      laura      None   skirt55    dress23       None    shirt47     coat45
```

Do a little data cleanup first and your results will look like.
New input df,

```
   Col 1       Col 2    Col 3
0  laura  purchase 1  dress23
1  laura  purchase 2  skirt55
2  laura  purchase 3  shirt47
3  laura  purchase 4   coat45
4  julia  purchase 1  skirt74
5  julia  purchase 2  short74
6  julia  purchase 3   coat14
7  julia  purchase 4   coat15
```

Now, execute pandas reshaping:

```
df.set_index(['Col 1','Col 2'])['Col 3'].unstack().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
Col 2  Col 1 purchase 1 purchase 2 purchase 3 purchase 4
0      julia    skirt74    short74     coat14     coat15
1      laura    dress23    skirt55    shirt47     coat45
```

## 2. Method pivot and reset_index

Or use `pivot` and `reset_index`:

```
df.pivot(index='Col 1',columns = 'Col 2', values= 'Col 3').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
Col 2  Col 1 purchase 1 purchase 2 purchase 3 purchase 4
0      julia    skirt74    short74     coat14     coat15
1      laura    dress23    skirt55    shirt47     coat45
```

Comment: You shouldn't copy and paste answers. ;-)

Comment: @DariusMorawiec :)  You are correct, good thing I didn't.  However, I will upvote your solution!  I like it.